# Interpretation of large error correction terms in VECM

Tags: econometrics, vector-error-correction-model

I've estimated a VECM model on four variable.

my results are

- Unit root test (ADF): all variables are I(1)
- Johansen rank test suggests estimating VECM with a trend and 1 cointegrating vector
- Estimation of VECM gives very large error correct terms  (estimated via the cajorls function in r, and then summary of model$rlm) : from -7 to 10
- Impulse response functions do also not converge

My question is how should I interpret these results? does it indicate stationarity in my variables?
I would be very happy if someone could point me in the direction of some literature that handles this case.